# Expectation of the ratio of sum (XY) and sum(X)

Tags: expected-value, autoregressive, asymptotics

I want to know (mathematically) how the following expression changes as $M$ increases but still have no clue after thinking about it for a while. Any suggestions or comments will be much appreciated.

$$E\left[ {\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\sigma _{0,i}^2}}{{1 - \varphi _i^2}} \cdot \left( {5 - 4\varphi _i^2} \right)} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\sigma _{0,i}^2}}{{1 - \varphi _i^2}}} }}} \right]$$

where $\sigma _{0,i}^2 \sim U\left( {a,b} \right),b > a > 0$ and $\varphi _i^2 \sim U\left( {0,1} \right)$.

This expression is the expectation of the ratio of the variance of the total output of a system and the total variance of $M$ different input stationary autoregressive (AR(1)) sequences.

According to @Sextus Empiricus's answer, if we denote $\alpha_{i}=1-\varphi_{i}^{2} \sim U(0,1)$ and $\beta_{i}=\sigma_{0, i}^{2} \sim U(a, b)$, the expression can be simplified as

$$E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M} \frac{\beta_{i}}{\alpha_{1}} \cdot\left(1+4 \alpha_{i}\right)}{\sum_{i=1}^{M} \frac{\beta_{i}}{\alpha_{i}}}\right]=E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M} (\frac{\beta_{i}}{\alpha_{i}}+4 \beta_{i})}{\sum_{i=1}^{M} \frac{\beta_{i}}{\alpha_{i}}}\right]=1+4E\left[\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M} \beta_{i}}{\sum_{i=1}^{M} \frac{\beta_{i}}{\alpha_{i}}}\right]$$

Comment: I am actually also curious about the background of this problem and maybe that helps to understand it.

Comment: If the mean value of $1/\alpha$ exists, denoted by $\mu_{(1/\alpha)}$, then for large values of $M$ the expression becomes $(\mu_{(1/\alpha)})^{-1}$.

Comment: @Jayzu, that's the fun of it, that mean value doesn't exist (although the sample mean does, of course, still exist).

Comment: When $\beta_i=1$, we have

$1+4 M\cdot E\left[ \frac{1}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{1}{{{\alpha _i}}}} }\right]$. 
If the mean of $1/\alpha_i$ exists, denoted by $\mu_{1/\alpha}$, then the expression is simplified to
$1+4 \cdot \frac{1}{\mu_{1/\alpha}} = 1+4 \cdot \frac{1}{\ln \infty} < 1+4\cdot E\left[ \alpha _i\right]=2$. 
So for large values of $M$, the value of the simpler form is less than that for $M=1$.

Comment: @Jayzu I don't believe that you can use that approximation when the mean is infinite.

Comment: Right. We can left truncate $\alpha_i$, say $\alpha_i \in (10^{-8}, 1)$, then $1/\alpha_i \in (1, 10^{8})$, then the mean exists, but this is the original case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*I will assume $a=0$ and $b=1$ in the following.*

Here is a simulation experiment to look at the variability of the expectation in $M$:

```
e=rep(0,N)
f=matrix(0,T,N)
for(t in 1:T){
  phi2=runif(N)
  we=runif(N)/(1-phi2)
  f[t,]=cumsum(we*(5-4*phi2))/cumsum(we)
  e=e+f[t,]}
```

with the plot of the averaged `e` (in red) against the `f[t,]`'s (in gray):

[image]

The expectation thus appears to decrease with $M$. Due to the lack of expectation of the individual weights $\sigma^2_{0,i}/(1-\varphi_i^2)$, it is unclear that the average within the expectation enjoys a finite variance, as indicated by the repeated jumps in the individual gray curves.

Note that an equivalent expression for the expectation is
$$1+4\mathbb E^{U,W}\left[\sum_{i=1}^M U_i\Big/\sum_{i=1}^M W_i \right]$$
with$$(U_i,W_i)\sim \frac{u}{w^2}\mathbb I_{(0,1)}(u)\mathbb I_{w>u}$$
by a change of variables and that it is approximately
$$1+2\mathbb E^{W}[\overline W_M^{-1}]\tag{1}$$for $M$ large. (Or asymptotically equivalent by Slutsky's theorem.) Note also that the marginal distribution of the $W_i$'s is
$$W\sim \frac{(w\wedge 1)^2}{2w^2}=\frac{\mathbb I_{0<w<1}}{2}+
\frac{\mathbb I_{w>1}}{2w^2}$$
This means that an asymptotic equivalent to (1) is
$$1+4\mathbb E^{W}[1\big/(\overline S_{M/2}+\overline R_{M/2})]$$
where$$\overline S_{n}=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n U_i\qquad \overline R_n=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n V_i^{-1}\qquad U_i,V_i\sim\mathcal{U}(0,1)$$hence
$$1+8\mathbb E^{W}[1\big/(1+2\overline R_{M/2})]$$
Comparing the distribution of$$1+4\sum_{i=1}^M U_i\Big/\sum_{i=1}^M W_i$$ with the distribution of$$1+8\big/(1+2\overline R_{M})$$does not exhibit any significant difference:

[image]

[image]

The distribution of a sum of Pareto variates is [particularly intricate](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2099342?seq=4). However, the [limiting distribution](https://escholarship.org/content/qt8940b4k8/qt8940b4k8.pdf?t=lnqpml) of the centred average is a stable distribution. Namely,
$$\frac{\overline{R}_M-\log(M)-C}{\pi/2}\approx F_{1,1}$$
where $C\equiv 0.8744...$ and $F_{1,1}$ is the [stable distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution) for $\alpha=\beta=1$. With cdf
$$F_{1,1}(x)=2\left(1-\Phi(2/\sqrt\pi \exp\{-1/2-\pi x\sqrt2/4)\}\right)$$

Comment: This particular stable distribution is also the [Landau distribution](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau_distribution)

Answer (score 6):

In your case of $\text{sum}(XY)/\text{sum}(X)$ you have that the $X$ and $Y$ are correlated. We can rewrite it in a different form such that we have a similar weighted average expression but with uncorrelated $X$ and $Y$.

You will get that you can relate it to the following expression:

$$1 + 4 E\left[\left(\frac{\sum_{i=1}^{M} X_iZ_i}{\sum_{i=1}^{M} X_i}\right)^{-1}\right]$$

where the weights are $X_i \sim U(a,b)$ and the variable $Z_i \sim Pareto(\alpha = 1, x_m = 1)$ follows a [Pareto distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pareto_distribution).

Possibly it is easier to first solve the simpler (but still difficult) problem with $\beta_i = 1$ constant.

$$E\left[\left(\frac{1}{M}{\sum_{i=1}^{M} Z_i}\right)^{-1}\right]$$

---

#### Derivation

The equation could be simplified (easier to read) by using different variables like $\alpha_i = 1-\varphi_i^2 \sim U(0,1)$ and $\beta_{i} = \phi_{0,i}^2 \sim U(a,b)$ such that your question becomes $$E\left[ {\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta_{i}}}{{\alpha_i}} \cdot \left( {1+4\alpha_i } \right)} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta_{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}} \right]$$

where $\beta _{i} \sim U\left( {a,b} \right),b > a > 0$ and $\alpha_i \sim U\left( {0,1} \right)$.

The expression can also be simplified further
$$E\left[ {\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta_{i}}}{{\alpha_i}} \cdot \left( {1+4\alpha_i } \right)} }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta_{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}} \right] =   E\left[ {\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M { \frac{{\beta_{i}}}{{\alpha_i}} + 4 \beta_{i}  } }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta _{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}} \right]=   E\left[ {\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M { \frac{{\beta_{i}}}{{\alpha_i}} + \sum\limits_{i = 1}^M 4 \beta_{i}  } }}{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta _{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}} \right] =   1 + 4 \cdot E\left[ {\frac{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M  \beta_{i} }{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta _{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}} \right]$$

#### Alternative viewpoint as random walk

- For $M=1$ we get:

  $$1 + 4 \cdot E\left[  \frac{\beta_{1}}{\frac{\beta _{1}}{\alpha_1}}  \right] = 1 + 4 \cdot E\left[  {\alpha_1}  \right] = 3$$
- For $M=2$ we get:

  $$1 + 4 \cdot E\left[  \frac{\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}}{\frac{\beta _{1}}{\alpha_1} + \frac{\beta_{2}}{\alpha_2}}  \right] = 1 + 4 \cdot E\left[  \frac{\beta_{1}\alpha_2\cdot \alpha_1 + \beta_{2}\alpha_1\cdot \alpha_2}{\beta_{1}\alpha_2\phantom{\cdot \alpha_1} + \beta_{2}\alpha_1\phantom{\cdot \alpha_1} }  \right] $$
- For $M=3$ we get:

  $$1 + 4 \cdot E\left[  \frac{\beta_{1} + \beta_{2}}{\frac{\beta _{1}}{\alpha_1} + \frac{\beta_{2}}{\alpha_2}}  \right] = 1 + 4 \cdot E\left[  \frac{\beta_{1}\alpha_2\alpha_3\cdot \alpha_1 + \beta_{2}\alpha_1\alpha_3\cdot \alpha_2+ \beta_{3}\alpha_1\alpha_2\cdot \alpha_3}{\beta_{1}\alpha_2\alpha_3 \phantom{\cdot \alpha_1} + \beta_{2}\alpha_1\alpha_3 \phantom{\cdot \alpha_1} + \beta_{3}\alpha_1\alpha_2\phantom{\cdot \alpha_1} }  \right] $$
- For more general $M$

  You seem to get the expectation of a weighted average of $\alpha_i$ where the wheighing is $\beta_i \prod_{l \neq i} \alpha_l $.

  $$X_{k} = \frac{\sum_{i = 1}^k \left( \beta_i \prod_{l \neq i} \alpha_l \right) \cdot \alpha_i} {\sum_{i = 1}^k \left( \beta_i \prod_{l \neq i} \alpha_l \right)}$$

When we add a sample $\beta_{k+1},\alpha_{k+1}$ to a sample of size $k$ then we can recompute the value as

$$X_{k+1} = \frac{\left(Q_k\alpha_{k+1}\right) \cdot X_{k} + \left(\beta_{k+1} \prod_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \right) \cdot \alpha_{k+1}}{\left(Q_k\alpha_{k+1}\right) \hphantom{\cdot X_{k}} + \left(\beta_{k+1} \prod_{i=1}^k \alpha_i \right) \hphantom{\cdot \alpha_{k+1}}} $$

where $Q_k = \sum_{i = 1}^k \left( \beta_i \prod_{k \neq i} \alpha_k \right)$

This seems like some sort of random walk

$$X_{k+1} = \phi_{k+1} X_k +  (1-\phi_{k+1}) \alpha_{k+1}$$

with $$\phi_{k+1} = \frac{Q_k\alpha_{k+1}}{Q_k\alpha_{k+1} + \beta_{k+1} P_k } $$

and $P_{k+1} = P_{k} \alpha_{k+1}$ and $Q_{k+1} = Q_k \alpha_{k+1} + P_k \beta_{k+1}$

The below code demonstrates this alternative view of how the random variable $X_n$ evolves from $n$ to $n+1$

```
a = 1
b = 3
alpha = runif(1,0,1)
beta = runif(1,a,b)
X = alpha
Q = beta
P = 1
for (i in 1:1000) {
  alpha_n = runif(1,0,1)
  beta_n = runif(1,a,b)
  alpha = c(alpha, alpha_n)
  beta = c(beta, beta_n)
  
  phi = Q*alpha_n /(Q*alpha_n + P*beta_n)
  X = c(X,phi * tail(X,1) + (1-phi) * alpha_n)
  Q = Q * alpha_n + P * beta_n 
  P = P * alpha_n
}

### two different ways to compute a series of X
plot(X*4+1, type = "l")
plot(1+4*cumsum(beta)/cumsum(beta/alpha), type = "l")
```

I wonder if we can use this iterative process to express the expectation value as some recursive relationship.

#### Geometric interpretation

The problem is equivalent to evaluating the expression

$$E\left[ \left( \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta _{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M  \beta_{i} } \right)^{-1}\right]$$

with $\alpha_i \sim U(0,1)$ and $\beta_i \sim U(a,b)$

We can focus on the sum inside

$$\frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta _{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M  \beta_{i} }$$

This is equal to the integral of a random path which that is created by ordering the $\alpha_i$ and making a horizontal step of size $\frac{\beta_i}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M  \beta_{i} }$ at a height of $\alpha$

[image: random curve]

Let this curve be $\alpha(x)$ then we have

$$ \int_0^1 \frac{1}{\alpha(x)} dx =  \frac{{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M {\frac{{\beta _{i}}}{{\alpha_i}}} }}{\sum\limits_{i = 1}^M  \beta_{i} }$$

and we can see the expectation as

$$E\left[\frac{1}{\int_0^1 \frac{1}{\alpha(x)} dx }\right]$$

here this curve $\alpha(x)$ resembles an empirical distribution function for a uniform variable.

Comment: Are you saying that since phi_i is uniform over [0, 1], 1 - phi^2 will also be uniform over [0, 1]?

Comment: @Seb It's $\varphi_i^2$ that's uniform. And if it's between 0 and 1, then so is $1 - \varphi_i^2$.

Comment: You’re right, apparently I can’t read

Comment: And that's exactly why I came up with the simplification.

Comment: I believe that for $M \to \infty$ the distribution does not approach a stable distribution. Say we have the variable $Y_i$ that follows this stable distribution, then we must have that $$\frac{1}{Y_1} \sim 0.5 \left( \frac{1}{Y_2} + \frac{1}{Y_3} \right)$$ which suggests that $\frac{1}{Y}$ should be a stable distribution and more specifically a normal distribution (which is the only option), but that is contradicting that the values are all positive.

Comment: I made a mistake in that last comment. It suggests that $\frac{1}{Y}$ is a stable distribution with $\alpha =1$ (the normal distribution would be the case with $\alpha =2$).

Comment: @Xi'an and a shift with some factor that includes $\log M$. So the distribution of the mean of a sample of size $M$ of different $1/Y$ will be some distribution whose probability mass will slowly shift to infinity.

Comment: @Xi'an I thought of ordering the $\alpha_i$ such that this becomes like a sort of empirical distribution of $\alpha$. I see now that it is actually a quantile distribution. The x-axis is the quantile or the cumulative amount of weight, and the y-axis is the value of $\alpha$.